# mysql-workbench: Error log Permission denied

Tags: permissions, mysql

I recently installed `mysql-workbench` by installing first `apt-config.deb` from `mysql` website and then install the actuall mysql with `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbenh` (I used sudo for almost everything). When I run the program I get errors in the console like this:

> Exception in logger: Could not create directory /home/nosthertus/.mysql/workbench/log: Permission denied
>
> Ready.
>
> I/O error : Permission denied
>   I/O error : Permission denied

For a moment I thought I just don't have permission to write/execute in `.mysql` folder, so to check I executed `ll` and found this:

```
drwxr-xr--  3 root       root       4096 mar  5 18:49 .mysql/
```

I tried to change permissions using `sudo chmod 757 .mysql`, but when I execute the program again, I get the error `I/O error: Permission denied`

This does not happen when I run `mysql-workbench` with `sudo`.. but I don't want to be executing a terminal for each program that needs to do the same process for permissions and I need the console for logging my errors on the applications I code.

Comment: You probably need to change the *ownership* rather than the permissions e.g. (assuming your username and primary group are both `nosthertus`), `sudo chown -R nosthertus:nosthertus ~/.mysql`. Then restore the original permissions on the directory (likely 755).

Comment: I tried your method and errors no longer appears.. is this the recommended way to do after installing applications through sudo?

Comment: You'd need to provide details of exactly what commands you ran in order for anyone to identify which (if any) should have been run using sudo

Comment: @steeldriver i did provide the details of the commands i ran.

Comment: Huh? *"I recently installed mysql-workbench using sudo (I used sudo for almost everything)"*

Comment: @steeldriver oh that.. i just realized that i did say i was new to ubuntu and one of the edits deleted that.

Comment: @steeldriver i will make a change providing how i installed `mysql-workbench`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem happens because `.mysql` was created by `root` user using `sudo` and the permissions are to only read for others that are not the owner..

To simply fix this issue, change the owner of the folder to the desired user using this command in terminal:

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<group> .mysql
```

what this command does? i will explain each one of them

`sudo` stands for "switch user and do" which is actually changing the user to root internally for this operation

`chown` stands for "change owner" and it does what actually it means, of course for this command to work properly on a folder. the owner of the folder has to run it, in this case was root so `sudo` was necessary

`-R` this parameter is actually from `chown` and it applies the same command recursively to all sub folders/files

`<user>:<group>` this is just the desired owner and group we would like to assign to folder/file and its a mandatory parameter from `chown`. Also you have to enter the source of the folder/file next to this parameter

you can check more options for `chown` using `man chown`

Comment: after I did this, workbench has issues starting as it was unable to open some files, wrong permission :-/. SO I had to change permissions back and just save in a non root area.